Async call to a func defined in extension from an isolated function in an actor preserves the isolation?
I have this setup:
protocol Foo {
    func foo() async
}

extension Foo {
    func foo() async {
        print("default implementation")
    }
}

final actor Bar: Foo {
    func run() async {
         print("this function is isolated on actor Bar")
         await self.foo()
    }

}


I have a function foo in an extension of a protocol Foo and it's async.
I have an actor Bar that implements Foo.
And I have an isolated function Bar.run which calls foo, which will be resolved to an implementation from the static extension

Question: will the foo be run on the actor Bar? Or the actor will be released because it's an async call outside the scope of actor?

Extremely similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78790268/async-call-to-a-func-defined-in-extension-from-an-isolated-function-in-an-actor, which was closed. Why exactly would the outcome here be different?

I'm not sure why the previous question was closed. This feels like a pretty solid question, and gets to an interesting subtlety that I think is important for folks trying to understand how isolation works. (I wasn't completely certain of the answer myself until I played around with some code to explore it, at which point it all made sense, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me.)

@matt 1) I didn't provide debugging details at first, it was closed; 2) I edited and submitted for review; 3) question never exited review; 4) I recreated it cuz I would really like for someone to answer it

No.
If foo() were really in the same isolation context, then it should be able to access synchronous function without awaiting. And I could define that:
protocol Foo {
    func foo() async
    func sync()  // Adding a new synchronous requirement
}

extension Foo {
    func foo() async {
        print("default implementation")
        sync() // And this should be fine
    }
}

But it is not possible to implement this with an actor within its isolation:
final actor Bar: Foo {
    func run() async { ... }

    func sync() {}
    // -> Actor-isolated instance method 'sync()' cannot be used to satisfy nonisolated protocol requirement
}

In order for Bar to implement Foo, sync() must be nonisolated:
// This is fine
final actor Bar: Foo {
    func run() async { ... }

    nonisolated func sync() {}
}

So the default implementation of foo() cannot synchronously access isolated parts of Bar.

hey... I just found out, that I can mark Foo as inheriting from the protocol... Actor.... I wonder, if this will change everything
